# Obtener valor de argumento de una funcion en javascript y por medio de ajax con jquery enviarlo a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

> Obtener valor de argumento de una función en javascript y por medio de ajax con jquery enviarlo a php

```
f_categorias(); 
function categorias(id){
    /*llega el argumento Categoria_1*/ id id.split("_");
/*aqui se separa quedando Categoria, 1*/ 
var spurl = ''; var p = ''; 
switch (id[0]) /*segun sea la opcion que llegue 'Categoria o Departamento'*/ { 
    case 'Categoria'://entraria aqui y defino variables para asignar valores 
        spurl = 'servicios.php'; 
        p = 'obtenerDatos'; 
        break; 
    case 'Departamento': 
          spurl = 'paquetes.php'; 
          p = 'obtenerDatos'; 
          break; } 
$.ajax({ url: spurl,/*en el ajax uso las variables de arriba */ 
         type: "POST", 
         data: { peticion: p, 
         idsp: id[1]} 
       /*y aqui es mi duda para capturar el id y llevarlo a php*/ 
 }).done(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      var result = JSON.parse(res); } }
 /*cierre de function */ <!-
```

Comment: Cual es tu problema para capturar el id? Por lo que veo defines la variable id y luego la separas en 2 partes. 0 es el nombre y 1 es el id. Luego en el ajax envias la información con ```{peticion: p, idsp:id[1]}``` quizás lo único que vea mal es que no le pones el = en ```id id.split("_");``` Aunque yo utilizo el ```success``` en ajax en vez del ```.done```

Comment: Si así es como lo comentas , el detalle era que al enviarlo al PHP el idsp:ID[1] como era un objeto JSON en el php al recibirlo tenía que decodearlo con JSON decide, recibí en php $variable= $_POST["idsp"];

Comment: Así es como comentas, el detalle era en el php no sabía cómo obtener el valor de idsp, pero ya me ayudaron , es de la siguiente manera en el php declaras una variable $variable=$_POST["idsp"]; $data=json_decode($variable); y así pude obtener el parámetro ya que desde Ajax venía en objeto JSON y para poder manejarlo en php hay que decodearlo, de antemano muchas gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo.